# extract some rows from excel to another txt by txt

Tags: python

I have a txt file that contains just the number like 218158, 177549
and I have a large excel file that have many columns and rows,
each rows related to one id

I want to read a number from txt file and then go to this number in (row)
and save all column for this row to another txt with tab

for example
in the txt: 218158
we go to the row what is number 218158 ( this number that already found at the left on excel) and save all info to txt with tab which : Jack         6       77667656
so this info is go to txt by tab
and so on
How can I do this by python

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/), here's an example of how it's done.

```py
import openpyxl

xlsx_file_path = r'ex.xlsx'
input_text_file_path = r'ex.txt'
output_text_file = r'out.txt'

with open(input_text_file_path,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

file = openpyxl.open(xlsx_file_path, read_only=True)  # open xlsx file

sheet_obj = file.active
for line in lines:
    row_id = int(line)  # read the number from the text file
    out_text = ""  # to hold the read string
    col = 1
    while True:
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=row_id,column=col).value
        if cell_obj is None:  # if cell is empty
            break
        else:
            out_text += str(cell_obj) + "\t"  # append the text in cell to the saved text
            col += 1

    with open(output_text_file,'a') as f:  # open output file to write in it
        f.write(out_text)
        f.write('/n')

file.close()  # close xlsx file
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-39f42f532cef> in <module>()
      5 
      6 with open(input_text_file_path,'r') as f:
----> 7     row_id = int(f.read()) #read the number from the text file
      8 
      9 file = openpyxl.open(xlsx_file_path, read_only=True)  # open xlsx file

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '218159\n177550\n196629\n157234\n104292\n217248\n48371\n83274\n56373\n169951\n89773\n103660\n17077\n98867\n97142\n78805

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I edited the code, you file contains many numbers.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'openpyxl' has no attribute 'open' , this error will appear .. can you give me the version of openpyxl?

Comment: @ARWAABDULKADERBASHANFAR openpyxl is `3.0.9` where this code ran, you can swap `openpyxl.open` with `openpyxl.load_workbook` for older versions.